# Шифрование и режимы шифрования

Tags: криптография, безопасность, blowfish

Приветствую. Разбираюсь с алгоритмом BlowFish. Есть этот алгоритм, который занимается шифровкой, а когда использовать режимы шифрования(CRT, CBC...)?
В Вики написано "метод применения блочного шифра (алгоритма), позволяющий преобразовать последовательность блоков открытых данных в последовательность блоков зашифрованных данных". Разве BlowFish не делает то же самое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть алгоритмы (BlowFish, TwoFish, AES, DES) и так далее. Они шифруют один блок данных. Сами алгоритмы отличаются. А вот режимы применения алгоритмов - как надстройки над шифрованием одного блока. Все эти CBC, CTR, OFB могут без особых изменений работать с любыми блочными шифрами. Целесообразность применения режимов зависит от задачи. CTR, например, годен для произвольного доступа к данным, когда нужно чтобы одинаковые блоки после шифрования были разными.

Comment: А режимы используется с алгоритмом или после работы алгоритма, отдельно?

Comment: @Romeon0 ну тут как посмотреть... Например шифруется не блок данных, а IV и результатом шифрования ксорятся сами данные. Это С алгоритмом или ПОСЛЕ?